# MediaPlayer.create cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to get an mp3 file to play a sound when a button is clicked (Android app). However, despite following tutorials with similar code, I get this error message 'MediaPlayer.create cannot be resolved as a type. I have refreshed the project and cleaned the project and it made no difference. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.h.a.t;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Hypo_Info extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hypo_info);

        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pill_bottle);

        Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.treatment_hypo);



        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Hypo_Info.this, Hypo_Treatment.class);
                startActivity(i);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: You shold to remove the `new` statement: `final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pill_bottle);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "new" keyword here:

```
new MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pill_bottle);
```

because the [MediaPlayer.create](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) is a **static** method.

==> remove the `new`

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much, it saved me a lot of time!